# Django - django-cookie-consent not working

Tags: python, django, cookies, gdprconsentform

https://github.com/haricot/django-cookie-consent

https://django-cookie-consent.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

I found a fork of the django-cookie-consent github project for managing cookies on your website and I got it to work most of the time but it is not 100% perfect.

Here is how I got it to run (either install via pip from that fork link or):

Do not use pip3 install django-cookie-consent from the default PyPi. Download the zip file from github and copy the cookie_consent folder to your site packages folder. For example for me it was - /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project_name/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cookie_consent. Then pip3 install django-appconf. Then follow the documentation instructions.

Links:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/cookies/

http://127.0.0.1:8000/cookies/accept/

http://127.0.0.1:8000/cookies/accept/variable_name/

http://127.0.0.1:8000/cookies/decline/

http://127.0.0.1:8000/cookies/decline/variable_name/

I found some code for the consent banner https://github.com/haricot/django-cookie-consent/tree/master/tests/core/templates but was having problems with it. I copied the test_page.html template code to my own project's base.html but this entire script tag did not work for me -> `<script type="{% cc_receipts "social" %}" data-varname="social">`. I got django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'cc_receipts' did not receive value(s) for the argument(s): 'request'. Copying the rest of the code from that file and not including that one script tag did cause the banner to show up on my project's base.html file.

Accepting a cookie from clicking accept on the banner code found from the tests directory just redirects me to a blank /cookies/accept/social/ page. This acceptance does not get logged either.

Accepting a cookie from /cookies/ does get logged but it gave me this error:

TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

[20/Jan/2020 16:00:43] "POST /cookies/accept/social/ HTTP/1.1" 500 121416

Method Not Allowed (GET): /cookies/accept/social/

Method Not Allowed: /cookies/accept/social/

[20/Jan/2020 16:00:44] "GET /cookies/accept/social/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Is this error a possible python3 incompatibility issue?

How would I configure, for example, where a group variable name called social and a cookie named 1P_JAR (this is an example of a recaptcha v3 cookie on my site).

Noticed that the username is not being logged or the the user's IP address. It would be nice to include these once they accept or decline.

I am not sure if this fork automatically blocks cookies until the user accepts. Can someone verify this? If this feature is or is not included, how do you implement it?

When accepting cookies or declining cookies, an actual cookie called cookie_consent gets created in your browser and it tells you which cookies are accepted or declined.

Can someone please help me get this to work? It seems very close to being GDPR compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Check your runserver log. You have to set up COOKIE_CONSENT_NAME setting. Because there is no default value for this setting.

Then you have to go to django admin panel and create the cookies with their respective names and domains which you can find in the browser inspector.

Answer (score 0):

how does it works: in creates a cookie labelled cookie_consent, this stores all the data necessary for this package to work. to make it work properly, several tweaks are required:

1)into setting.py you must indicate `COOKIE_CONSENT_NAME = "cookie_consent"` (or whatever you like probably works too)

2. into TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS copy: `'django.template.context_processors.request'` --OR-- copy into:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                "django.template.context_processors.request", 
                ...
```

3)[NOT MANDATORY BUT HELPFUL, see instuctions on django documentation] i have also indicated into setting COOKIE_CONSENT_CACHE_BACKEND = "default" plus
setted the whole website cache to: `django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache`

then you create on the admin page firstly a cookie group into cookie groups window, WITHOUT checking the `Is required` checkbox (otherwise you are not able to manage the cookie group because the checkbox implies that these cookies are always on and thus the user cannot decide or not to eliminate them); then you must also add at least 1 cookie for cookie group
(otherwise the get_version will not work for cookie groups and its mandatory to the correct use of the library)

consensus is gathered for groups and not for each cookie (As GDPR suggests), meaning that the `accept_cookies(request, response, varname="your_cookie_group")` will only works if you use cookie groups.

this is an exaple of the functions (not perfect) telling to accept the cookie from view, to work it requires obviously two refresh, the first to set the cookie, the second to see it:

```
---views.py
def homepage(request):
    
    #to render the page
    response = render(request = request, 
                  ...

    #to accept a cookie group
    accept_cookies(request, response, varname="cookie_group")#probabilmente solo per cookie groups
    
    #to check the cookie group
    cc = get_cookie_value_from_request(request, varname='cookie_group')
    print("cookie value from request: ",cc)

    if cc == True:
        print("Consensus given", cc)
    elif cc==False:
        print("Consensus not given",cc)
    else:
        print("probable error in getting cookie value from request: ", cc) # problem with cookie group


    return response
```

```
---urls.py
path('', views.homepage, name ="home")
```